# How To Display Null Values In CGridView when there is a null value in foreignkey Table IN Yii

Tags: php, yii

If I use INNER Join the following code works well, but for LEFT JOIN its showing "Trying to get property of non-object". I need to use Left Join here because `outlet_id` is not a mandatory field, it may be null. If `outlet_id` is set then I want to show outlet name otherwise just blank.

**My Model :**

```
public function relations()
            {
                    'outlet' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Outlets',         'outlet_id','joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN','select'=>'id,name'),
            }
    //Search Function
    public function search()
        {
            // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
                $criteria->with = array(
                   'outlet' => array(
                        'joinType' => 'LEFT JOIN',
                        'select'=>'name',
                    ),

                );

        $criteria->compare('outlet_id',$this->outlet_id,true);
      $criteria->compare('outlet.name',$this->outlet_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('session_id',$this->session_id,true);


        $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);
        $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
                $criteria->together = true; 
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'sort' => array(
                //'defaultOrder'=>'LTRIM(t.name) ASC',
                'defaultOrder' => 't.id DESC',
            ),
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 50,
            ),
        ));
    }
```

**My View :**

```
<?php 
//pr($model->search(),1);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'company-details-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'filter' => $model,
    'columns'=>array(
            array(
                    'class' => 'IndexColumn',
                    'header' => 'S.No.',
                ),
        array(
           'name'=>'id',
            'header'=>'ID',
            'value'=>'$data->id',
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'outlet_name',
                 'value' => '($data->outlet->name)',
            ), 
    ),
));
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you are trying to get the value of `$data->outlet->name` when `$data->outlet` is `null` instead of an instance of your outlet model.

Use a condition in your `value` statement to check whether `$data->outlet` is valid:

```
array(
    'name' => 'outlet_name',
    'value' => '($data->outlet_id ? $data->outlet->name : "-")',
)
```

Comment: I have tried this already but Not work.
My issue is when i use Join Type Left in cdbCriteria its giving error that "Trying to get property of non-object " If i use JOIN its ok. But I need all the rows which have outlet_id is available or not.  Means Need Left JOIN with Outlets Table.

Comment: OK. What is the error in full and what line does it reference?

Comment: Error :  "Trying to get property of non-object " Error In Below
array(
            'name' => 'outlet_name',
                 'value' => '($data->outlet->name)',
            ),

Comment: Issue : If I Use INNER Join It works well; But for LEFT JOIN its showing "Trying to get property of non-object " . I need To Use Left Join here Because In Outlet_id Is not mandatory field it may be null. I Just Wantthat If its (outlet_id) available then Want To show Outlet Name otherwise Just Blank.

Comment: Then check for outlet_id as I have edited the answer to read.